# force Jaxb2/Spring to assume xml version 1.1 when unmarshalling Soap messages

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

a legacy service we have to integrate exposes a SOAP endpoint, that sometimes - without any indication how or why - returns documents that contain characters that are invalid in xml version 1.0, but valid in version 1.1.

As this services behavior cannot be changed - our Spring Boot app has to "assume" xml version 1.1 when unmarshalling the response we get.

Is there a way to specify the xml-version Jaxb2Marshaller assumes when unmarshalling if no xml header is given?